# Deployment Environment Responsibility

Tags: development-environment, agile

This might be not technical but rather process driven query. Help me redirect to right forum if this is not the place to ask such question.

Typically in a project, we have a deployment environment where development team deploy the code for testing purpose. Testing team executes test cases on the environment.

But I have seen projects where there are multiple environments for different teams to test on, and when I get to understand that what's the point? I do not see any reason than to have multiple environments.

***Two environments:***

**1. Lower Environment**  - Developers can use this environment to test their code( this environment will be an exact replica of higher environment where Internal and External testing will happen)

**2. Higher Environment** - where multiple testing team can test which from my experience seems stable env. to test on.

But I see multiple environment where testing happens with no apparent concrete reason. My question is who's responsibility to support multiple environments? I find it difficult for development team to work on supporting multiple environments apart from regular dev activities, Unit test case preparation, get clarification from the design or business on User story.

Any suggesstion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a better fit for Programmers.SE

Answer (score 3):

> My question is who's responsibility to support multiple environments?

Depending upon the size and roles that you have in the team, responsibility would usually lie with either one of the developer, tester, or release manager.

> I find it difficult for development team to work on supporting multiple environments apart from regular dev activities

**Deployments** across environments can be and should be **automated**. Make sure that a proper source control tool is in place and all developers check-in the code there. Scripts can be created once and used for every deployment. There are *Continuous Integration* tools available which can help with automated deployment as well by fetching the code from source control repository and making an application build from it. This will save everyone's time and minimize human errors.

---

**Release management best practices** involve setting up different environments which are mainly:

- Development
- Test/QA
- Staging
- Production/Live

*Development environment:*

This is where development team run their code. It could be the developer's workstation or a server shared by several developers working together on the same project. This environment is frequently updated by the developers, so testers may not be able to use this environment for executing proper test cycles. Anyone from the dev team can update it. This is what you have termed as a *Lower Environment*.

*Test environment:*

A place where testing can be conducted. This would include functional testing as well as performance testing in a physical environment with hardware and software that is identical to the production environment. This environment is less frequently updated and provides a common platform for testers to report bugs on. Testers would not have to worry about frequent updates (by developers) and at the same time developers would not have to wait for the test cycle to complete so that they can update this environment. Updates to this environment should be scheduled and properly announced to the related group. Updates to this environment should be automated but controlled by the QA team/manager.

*Staging environment:*

This is preferred to be a mirror of production setup. It is used as a pre-production location and contains the *Release Candidate* -- the next version of the application, planned to be made live. Final testing and client/manager approvals are done here. It is used to verify installation, configuration, and migration scripts / procedures, before they are applied to production environment. The software installed here should closely match the software installed in the production environment. However, it maybe acceptable that the hardware capability of staging environment can be lesser since this environment is not to be used for measuring performance. Updates to this environment are not frequent and highly controlled (done usually by the release manager). On some projects, the developer, the release manager, and QA tester can actually be the same person but it should be clear that the roles are different.

*Production environment:*

This is the live environment which is available to the all the end users. Similar to *staging*, only selected group should be able to update the live setup. A developer should not be making any changes directly to the *staging* or *production* environments.

Answer (score 0):

Hi on my previous work we also have different environment but here is the thing... on your case you have two environment which is lower and higher which is good.

my suggestion is you need a dedicated person who will be in-charge in all deployment. maybe you can call them "deployment person/team" , he will be the one to check all standards such as coding etc. of all developers and he will be the one to deploy in testing site (QA testing site) so that development team can focus on their task.

to be able to achieve that , you can use centralize repository for all developers such as Tortoise SVN etc.

Also , all developers can do the checking on their local computer.. if the program still have errors they are not allow to commit the changes in the repository if the errors not yet fixed to avoid deployment issues. If everything is fine, developers can now commit the codes in the repository, then the deployment team will check, if everything is good to both QA and Dev team, the deployment team can now deploy.

Hope it helps.

Regards.